# Aviso al enviar formulario PHP

Tags: php, email

Estoy enviando un formulario con SendGrid.¿Cómo hago para que me salga el aviso "Tu requerimiento ha sido enviado" o lo contrario en caso de que sea un fallo?,¿Cómo ejecuto $okMessage y $errorMessage?

**HTML**

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="enviar_email.php" role="form">
                    
                    <div class="messages"></div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" name="categoria">
                            <option>-- Selecciona una categoría --</option>
                            <option>Branding e identidad de marca</option>
                            <option>Comunicación interna</option>
                            <option>Diseño Editorial</option>
                            <option>Desarrollo Web</option>
                            <option>Multimedia y 3D</option>
                            <option>Redes Sociales</option>
                            <option>Marketing Electrónico</option>
                            <option>Diseño de Empaques</option>
                            <option>Otro</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="form_message" name="detalles" class="form-control" placeholder="Detalles *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Detalles requerido." ></textarea>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" required="required" data-error="Email requerido." />
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <input id="form_name" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre *" required="required" data-error="Nombre requerido.">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono *" required="required" data-error="Teléfono requerido.">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <p><small>Índice de respuesta: 1 hra. aproximadamente.</small></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4 text-right">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar Requerimiento">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </form>
```

**enviar_email.php**

```html
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

    $from = new SendGrid\Email('Name', "test@test.com");
    $subject = "Asunto";
    $to = new SendGrid\Email('Name', "test@test.com");
    
    $categoria = strip_tags($_POST['categoria']);
    $detalles = strip_tags($_POST['detalles']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
    $telefono = strip_tags($_POST['telefono']);

    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Hola, ha llegado un nuevo mensaje <br><br>Categoría: $categoria<br>Detalles: $detalles<br>Email: $email<br>Nombre: $nombre<br>Teléfono: $telefono<br>");


    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

    $okMessage = 'Tu requerimiento ha sido enviado.';
    $errorMessage = 'Se produjo un error, por favor inténtalo nuevamente.';

    $apiKey = 'MyApiKey';
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
    echo $response->statusCode();
    echo $response->headers();
    echo $response->body();   
?>
```

**PHP (anterior)**
Antes estaba usando este código y si me salía el aviso.

```html
<?php
 

// configure
$from       = 'Name <test@test.com>';
$sendTo     = 'Name <test@test.com>';
$subject    = 'Asunto';
$fields     = array('categoria' => 'Categoría', 'detalles' => 'Detalles', 'email' => 'Email', 'nombre' => 'Nombre', 'telefono' => 'Teléfono'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Tu mensaje ha sido enviado.';
$errorMessage = 'Se produjo un error, por favor inténtalo nuevamente.';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "Hola, ha llegado un nuevo requerimiento desde la web de Khapac.com<br><br>";

    
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value<br><hr style='border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;'>";
        }
    }
    
    
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}

    
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}

?>
```

**contact.js**

```js
$(function () {

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "enviar_email.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Cuales son los valores que te da `echo $response->statusCode()`? Debiera ser 200 en casi de éxito y 5xx en caso de fallo

Comment: Dónde se ven esos valores que mencionas? soy novato en esto, por favor serías tan amable de explicarme un poco más.

Comment: En este momento tu script termina escribiendo la salida en pantalla `echo $response->statusCode();`, 
`echo $response->headers();` y `echo $response->body();` . Péganos qué sale en esa impresión.

Comment: No me sale ninguna impresión. En todo caso hay otra forma de verlo?. Cuando termino de llenar el formulario y pulso enviar, lo envía correctamente (porque llega el correo), el único problema es que no me sale ningún aviso en el formulario. Pero no me sale ninguna impresión, mira: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0WbeREOiUiBalNzaWNHOEpZREU/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: @amenadiel solo me bota esta impresión: 202Array

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso, pareciera que lo único que necesitas saber es el statusCode de la respuesta. Tu código quedaría asi

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

$from = new SendGrid\Email('Name', "test@test.com");
$subject = "Asunto";
$to = new SendGrid\Email('Name', "test@test.com");

$categoria = strip_tags($_POST['categoria']);
$detalles = strip_tags($_POST['detalles']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
$telefono = strip_tags($_POST['telefono']);

$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Hola, ha llegado un nuevo mensaje <br><br>Categoría: $categoria<br>Detalles: $detalles<br>Email: $email<br>Nombre: $nombre<br>Teléfono: $telefono<br>");


$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$okMessage = 'Tu requerimiento ha sido enviado.';
$errorMessage = 'Se produjo un error, por favor inténtalo nuevamente.';

$apiKey = 'MyApiKey';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);

$status_code = $response->statusCode();

if( substr($status_code,0,1) == 2 )
    $responseArray = [
        'type' => 'success', 
        'message' => $okMessage,
        'status'=>$status_code
    ];
} else {
    $responseArray = [
        'type' => 'danger', 
        'message' => $errorMessage
        'status' => $status_code
        ];
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}


else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

El statusCode es un valor cuyo significado corresponde a uno de los [códigos de estado HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP). A grandes rasgos:

- Una respuesta 2xx es éxito
- Una respuesta 3xx es redirección
- Una respuesta 4xx es un error tuyo
- Una respuesta 5xx es un error de ellos

Por eso digo que si el primer dígito de la respuesta es un 2, entonces la petición funcionó bien. En caso contrario, mando el $error Message.

Comment: No me funciona (inclusive no envía). Lo he insertado entre `echo $response->statusCode();` y `echo $response->headers();` He quitado el corchete que estás usando antes de else. Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal? Una pregunta, el $responseArray de donde se ejecuta?

Comment: los corchetes son la notación corta de `array()`. La impresión de `$responseArray` vendría después del bucle `if {} else {}`.  Voy a editar mi respuesta para clarificar esa parte.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias @amenadiel me funcionó con unos ligeros ajustes de corchete y el array.

```html
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

    $from = new SendGrid\Email('Name', "test@test.com");
    $subject = "Asunto";
    $to = new SendGrid\Email('Name', "test@test.com");

    $categoria = strip_tags($_POST['categoria']);
    $detalles = strip_tags($_POST['detalles']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
    $telefono = strip_tags($_POST['telefono']);

    $content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "Hola, tienes un nuevo mensaje <br><br>Categoría: $categoria<br>Detalles: $detalles<br>Email: $email<br>Nombre: $nombre<br>Teléfono: $telefono<br>");


    $mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

    $okMessage = 'Tu mensaje ha sido enviado.';
    $errorMessage = 'Se produjo un error, por favor inténtalo nuevamente.';

    $apiKey = 'MyApiKey';
    $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

    $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
   

    
    $status_code = $response->statusCode();

    if( substr($status_code,0,1) == 2 )
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage, 'status'=> $status_code);
   

    else {
        $responseArray = array ('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage, 'status' => $status_code);
    }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}


else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}

?>
```

Comment: hmmm puede que estés usando una versión de PHP anterior a la 5.4, realmente no se me ocurrió. Me alegro de que te haya funcionado y sobre todo, que pudiste adaptar una solución genérica a tu caso de uso.